# Any way to add an associated url redirect to a content view?

Tags: views, commerce

I want to display the url redirect by which a user entered my site on the commerce orders view so that we can easily see if certain redirects we have set up for direct mails, magazine ads etc have been successful in generating an order. I can't seem to find a way to do this - I'm not a developer so would needs something that can be achieved through the cms.

I know I could do something similar with google analytics/campaigns but I can't use that for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set that variable in the user's `$_SESSION` and then when an order gets created, check to see if that `$_SESSION` variable is there when you save a new order and if it is, write it to `$order->data`.

Alternatively, you can check out [Commerce Affiliate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_affiliate) which allows you to set up affiliates and provides some extra conditions and actions that you can use. This includes grabbing URL params and storing them on the session.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea how to set a variable in a user's session, nor how to write it to the order unfortunately. I did look at commerce affiliate and it looked promising but I still don't seem to be able to get the info into the order view. Appreciate your time to answer the question.